# Calculate area and display pie chart by percentage in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to display a pie chart with the percentage of the area of each class in Google Earth Engine

here is the code:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/56a5d60822c733af20ce7bfd00fb5fab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with the keys in `lookup_names` and `lookup_palette`. If you print them, you'll see that the keys all end with `.0`. You can introduce a little utility function, to deal with the `ee.Number -> ee.String` conversion.

```
function toString(number) {
  return ee.Number(number).format('%d')
}
```

You can then use that function when mapping over `landcover`.

```
ee.List(landcover.get('landcover_class_values')).map(toString)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/2225b34b90703a417bdb1d87600e6417

Comment: Thank you so much! Daniel!